# Решето Эратосфена. Проблема

Tags: c, простые-числа

Решил написать свою версию на С "решето Эратосфена" на сегменте [2,M], Но почему-то считает неправильно. Например, 2 не входит в мое окончательное множество, и иногда появляется число (M+1)`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int search(int p);
int main()
{
    int M;
    printf("Enter number(M): ");
    scanf("%d", &M);
    int array[M]; //VLA
    if (M <= 1) exit(1);
    for (int i = 2; i <= M; i++)
    {
        array[i] = search(i);
        printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, array[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}

int search(int p)
{   
    int k;
    k = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= p; i++)
    {
        if(!(p % i))
        {
        k++;
        }
        if (!k) {return p; k = 0;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Первые (менее 10) простые числа обычно просто вписывают в код. Остальные проверяют.

Comment: Я просто решил в общем случае, так сказать, написать программу. Я вообще всегда так пишу обычно.

Comment: Вопрос не в тему. ВОт многие на сайте пишут, например, алгоритм сложности O(N). Где можно найти литературу по сложности алгоритма? Как я понимаю, это связано с матаном, ибо O, o - символы Ландау.

Comment: O() "большое О" - это оценка сложности. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C2%ABO%C2%BB_%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%C2%ABo%C2%BB_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B5 Например: О(1) - скорость обработки не меняется, О(N) - линейная зависимость.

Comment: А вы пробовали в гугле набирать Решето Эратосфена С?

Answer (score 4):

Приведённый код нельзя назвать решетом Эратосфена. По задумке он просто проверяет, простое ли число, для каждого из чисел диапазона.

Решето же не требует делений и проверок. В массиве просто помечаются составные числа, а в конце из него выбираются непомеченные. [Ideone](https://ideone.com/vqyoi4)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
int M = 12; 
int Primes[M + 1]; 
for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++) 
  Primes[i] = 1;
for (int i = 2; i * i <= M; i++) {
   if (Primes[i]) {
        int t = i * i;
        while (t <= M) {
            Primes[t] = 0;
            t += i;
        }
    } 
}    
for (int i = 2; i < M; i++) 
  if (Primes[i])
     printf("%d ", i);
return 0;   
}
2 3 5 7 11
```

Comment: Да, Вы наверно правы, я вообще не то написал.

Comment: Но у вас вроде Pascal, а как это на С делать без проверок? Там же нереально...

Comment: Это псевдокод. Нет разницы, какой язык - главное - принцип. Вот рабочий код на С++

Comment: Я смотрел, но я хотел написать его в рамках С

Comment: cout заменить на printf, и будет С

Comment: @Alexandrietz Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа)